# Wordpress wp-login undefined redirect

Tags: wordpress, authentication, undefined

After moving a wordpress installation from a remote server back to my localhost I ran into a problem I cannot seem to fix.

- downloaded all files and the database
- changed url's in the options db table
- changed the .htaccess to run in the right directory

For some reason, when I now go to the WP admin directory and I try to login, after I press the login button it redirects to /wp-login.phpundefined/. Note the undefined behind the wp-login.php. It, of course gives a 404 page. I'm also not logged in, when I go to the WP admin again I still need to login. The code of the login has the right form action, so it happens somewhere in the process of the login script.

Anybody any idea what might cause this? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `wp-config.php` to force the domain your WP installation is on.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If that doesn't work, use the [Fine and Replace](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool that will replace all instances of your site's URL from your old database to your new site URL.

i.e. Find and replace.

```
http://localhost/
```

to

```
http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp-login.php` can be used to (re-)set the URIs.

Find this line:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

and insert the following lines below:

```
// FIXME: do comment/remove these hack lines (once the database is updated).

update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
```